# Python Notebook kept on asking to open a local path with an app every time it initializes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently created a Github repo [for a particular work](https://github.com/lemslemslems/cell_thermal_calculations) and in the process I was also learning about user-defined extensions and planned to implement it for the first time in here. At first the system was not able to detect the extension, so I played around with the directories.

I did a "sys.path.append(os.getcwd())" in the hopes that the system detects the current directory and be able to find the user-defined extension. After a number of times adding and removing that command, it finally did but it added a pycache folder, which I was not too concerned of. **What did concern me though is that after using the extension, the notebook kept on prompting me this:**
[image: Prompt glitch]

After seeing that I tried deleting the extension altogether, along with the pycache file. I also did a "sys.path.remove(os.getcwd())", but nothing I did here fixed the problem.

This prompts only shows when I open this specific notebook. How do I fix this?

- Tried deleting the extension and the pycache folder
- Tried "sys.path.remove(os.getcwd())"
- Expected the prompt glitch issue stops persisting but it did